# Javascript function that return an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

this function read the current selected values from a table, I can't get the list of them in a single array readable outside this function.

```
function getcheckboxed() {
vartoberead = [];
$("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").each(function(){
    vartoberead [vartoberead .length] = $(this).val();
     console.log($(this).val(), vartoberead);
     return vartoberead;
});
```

I've declared *vartoberead*, both inside, than outside the function, tried with:

```
var myoutsidevar = getcheckboxed();
```

but always return

> [undefined]

Every help is appreciated

Comment: Side note. Instead of manually supplying the index you can use this syntax- `vartoberead.push($(this).val());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can shorten this up a bit:

```
var values = $("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Edit: To make this a function and return:

```
function getcheckboxed() { 
    return $("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: What does `get()` do in this instance?

Comment: `.get()` creates the basic Array @Curt -- else it'll be a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks +1, better than my solution

Comment: this run fine outside a function, is there a way to put it inside a function? if I do: function getcheckboxed() {
 var levalues = $("input:checkbox[name=dalinkare]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
return levalues;}

Comment: @user2239318 -- Yeah, that'll work - ill update the answer to include it in a function.

Comment: @user2239318 -- Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use map:

```
var vartoberead = $("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
});
```

`map()` does actually return something, so you don't need to push to an array but instead just let jQuery fill the array for you with the returned values.

Answer (score 0):

you should `return` after the `each()` cycle (and not inside the cycle as you're doing) anyway you could also use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
function getcheckboxed() {
   return $("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").serializeArray();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print the value inside de each ( console.log($(this).val(), vartoberead); ) it show the values correctly ?

Other thing is that you are returning the value inside the each.

Try this:

```
function getcheckboxed() {
    vartoberead = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=test]:checked").each(function(){
        vartoberead.push($(this).val());
    });
    return vartoberead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pure javascript solution for this . I have used html array i.e all checkboxes having same name (say test[])

```js
function getCheckBoxesValues()
{
 var values=[];
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('test[]').length;i++)
         
                {
                        if((document.getElementsByName('test[]')[i]).checked)
       {
        values.push((document.getElementsByName('test[]')[i]).value);
       }
                }
 return values;   
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="c1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="c2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="c3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="c4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="c5"/>
<button onClick="alert(getCheckBoxesValues());">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify you code to valid JavaScript code.
That is:
 `vartoberead [vartoberead .length]` should be `vartoberead[vartoberead.length]` without any spaces. Beside this issue everything else is ok with your code.

Just by looking at your code I would rather use `vartoberead.push($(this).val())` to add to the returned array than looking at the arrays length.